# Recovery from a trashing: exterminator first or disaster recovery cleaners first?

Tags: cleaning, pest

So, as part of the project that is my (inherited) house in southwestern Missouri, the house *finally* has been dejunked from the human-inflicted disaster that happened to it. (Worse tenants than us were involved.  I will leave it at that.)  However, the state it was left in also demands a thorough (disaster recovery thorough) cleaning, and also left the place open for four-legged, furry, squeaky tenants, as was discovered during the dejunking:

[image: mouse, in portraiture]

So, should I call in the disaster-recovery cleaners first to give the place a thorough scrubbing and then have all the squeakiness removed by the exterminator, or the exterminator first to evict the mice before the cleaners go to work?

Comment: Both.  Rough cleaning to remove food and bedding/habitat must come first.  Removal of the mice must include closing  the openings letting them in.  Followed by a final cleaning.

Comment: Lay traps & bait if you are comfortable with doing so. Light off a bug bomb if you are comfortable with doing so. BOTH will clear out some vermin immediately and reveal carpenter ants, bees, other "infestation" friends, revealing where you may have work to do in unseen areas. Also, CLEAN CLEAN CLEAN. Remove the reason they are there other than warmth. If you are going to call a service for both jobs, how much are you ready to do on your own? Also, will either service actually WORK in the conditions as they are now? You could be at their mercy unless you do up front effort.

Comment: @Tyson -- by "rough cleaning" -- do you mean removing junk and clutter, or actually *cleaning* things?  Because the former was just completed, but the latter I want to leave to the professionals here (if nothing else, because I don't exactly have vacation days to hurl at being down there on-site)

Comment: I mean remove food and items that they can bed down in.  Remove food and water sources. Don't give them a place to hide out.  Then get the openings closed up so they can't get in.  Then final spotless cleaning.

Comment: @Tyson, you didn't mention the exterminator in the then then then list, but I believe you meant it between "openings closed up..." & ".... final spotless cleaning"

Comment: Whatever you do don't touch live or dead furry critters (mice, rats) last year a man picked up a version of black plague in southern Oregon trying to save one from a cat. The cat died and he may have lost some fingers, I have also heard about valley feaver from droppings (from family members in southern California) don't know if this is an issue in Missouri but I had not heard of of these, so be cautious and have the pros do the dirty work.

Answer (score 1):

Clean up first. By removing their 'house', most of the vermin will leave on their own.

Comment: True with a but - if there is food sources outside of his control in the area surrounding the home they may extend their stay. Nonetheless, definitely need to clean anything that can be... Pick teh low hanging fruit!

Comment: Unfortunately, doing property maintenance, I've been here before. Exterminator will make sure there aren't any dangerous mythical beasts in there, but will tell you, you are wasting your time trying to exterminate in a mess.

Comment: Makes sense; unfortunately both are costly. Perhaps the cleaning service cost is less regardless. (Since an exterminator will certainly charge more for less access to the areas they treat)

Comment: @noybman -- considering this house is on an acreage, I don't think food source abatement from the surroundings is at all practical.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thanks for clarifying. I was more leaning towards densely populated areas with surrounding homes keeping the food coming. SInce thats not an issue, Bomb and trap/bait if you are acceptable of doing so and get the exterminator in there if the area is free and clear for him to work.